# Java implementation of Wil Shipley's `IsEmpty` method for defensive coding

Tags: java, objective-c

I'm an Objective-C guy starting work on a small personal Java project. In my Objective-C projects, I practice defensive coding and regularly use [Wil Shipley's `IsEmpty(id thing)` method](http://blog.wilshipley.com/2005/10/pimp-my-code-interlude-free-code.html) to check for null or empty values before use:

```m
static inline BOOL IsEmpty (id thing)
{
    return thing == nil
        || ([thing respondsToSelector:@selector(length)] && [(NSData *)thing length] == 0)
        || ([thing respondsToSelector:@selector(count)] && [(NSArray *)thing count] == 0);
}
```

I'm aware of that Apache Commons does something like this (although, it looks to me, only for String objects), and I've tried implementing something similar myself in Java, but can't find a way to call the `length()` or `size()` methods on an object when the class is unknown at compile time.

Am I trying to fit a square peg into a round hole? If not, how would a seasoned Java developer implement a generic check to ensure that a wide range of objects are not null, and are not empty if they implement the `.length()` or `.size()` methods?

**Edit:** While some answers focus on implementing an equivalent `isEmpty` method (and pgreen2's answer does seem to work) the real issue highlighted by *CodaFi* and *The Tosters* seems to be that Objective-C coding practices that take advantage of weak typing may not translate well to a strongly-typed paradigm like Java ("square peg, round hole"). Which isn't to say that either typing method is preferable; they're just different, and require different practices.

Comment: You just might be.  Objective-C inherited C's weaker-than-weak type system, then spread a layer of duck typing over it.  Java's a lot stricter by comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience but it looks like it has much weaker typing than java.  The first part of your questions is very simple.

```
//this checks for null objects
public static boolean isEmpty(Object o) {
  return o == null;
}
```

However, in your example code, you are checking for particular fields with specific names.  This is far more complex in java.  You can use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/), but you need to check for both methods and fields.  You will then need to check for the appropriate return types: Number, int, long, short, float, double.  So, it is possible, but would require a bunch of work and would be slow.

A simpler, yet more restrictive mechanism would be to only check for common types:
*(updated to fix bug with Enumeration and add array; array has to be broken down for each primative due to how arrays work in java)*

```
public static boolean isEmpty(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (o instanceof Object[]) {
        return ((Object[]) o).length <= 0;
    }
    else if (o instanceof boolean[]) {
        return ((boolean[]) o).length <= 0;
    }
    else if (o instanceof byte[]) {
        return ((byte[]) o).length <= 0;
    }
    else if (o instanceof short[]) {
        return ((short[]) o).length <= 0;
    }
    else if (o instanceof char[]) {
        return ((char[]) o).length <= 0;
    }
    else if (o instanceof int[]) {
        return ((int[]) o).length <= 0;
    }
    else if (o instanceof long[]) {
        return ((long[]) o).length <= 0;
    }
    else if (o instanceof float[]) {
        return ((float[]) o).length <= 0;
    }
    else if (o instanceof double[]) {
        return ((double[]) o).length <= 0;
    }
    else if (o instanceof CharSequence) {
        return ((CharSequence) o).length() <= 0;
    }
    else if (o instanceof Collection) {
        return ((Collection) o).isEmpty();
    }
    else if (o instanceof Map) {
        return ((Map) o).isEmpty();
    }
    else if (o instanceof Enumeration) {
        return !((Enumeration) o).hasMoreElements();
    }
    else if (o instanceof Dictionary) {
        return ((Dictionary) o).isEmpty();
    }
    else if (o instanceof Iterable) {
        // NOTE: may not be efficient because an iterator is created
        return !((Iterable) o).iterator().hasNext();
    }

  return false;
}
```

*Update: The following is the previous version with reflection to check for methods, the code could be expanded to support fields.  Handling the return types wasn't as difficult as I initially thought.  It seams the autoboxing works even with reflection.  I also threw in a check to see if the object has an isEmpty() boolean method.*

```
public static boolean isEmpty(final Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (o instanceof Object[]) {
        return ((Object[]) o).length <= 0;
    }
    else if (o instanceof boolean[]) {
        return ((boolean[]) o).length <= 0;
    }
    else if (o instanceof byte[]) {
        return ((byte[]) o).length <= 0;
    }
    else if (o instanceof short[]) {
        return ((short[]) o).length <= 0;
    }
    else if (o instanceof char[]) {
        return ((char[]) o).length <= 0;
    }
    else if (o instanceof int[]) {
        return ((int[]) o).length <= 0;
    }
    else if (o instanceof long[]) {
        return ((long[]) o).length <= 0;
    }
    else if (o instanceof float[]) {
        return ((float[]) o).length <= 0;
    }
    else if (o instanceof double[]) {
        return ((double[]) o).length <= 0;
    }
    else if (o instanceof CharSequence) {
        return ((CharSequence) o).length() <= 0;
    }
    else if (o instanceof Collection) {
        return ((Collection) o).isEmpty();
    }
    else if (o instanceof Map) {
        return ((Map) o).isEmpty();
    }
    else if (o instanceof Enumeration) {
        return !((Enumeration) o).hasMoreElements();
    }
    else if (o instanceof Dictionary) {
        return ((Dictionary) o).isEmpty();
    }
    else if (o instanceof Iterable) {
        // NOTE: may not be efficient because an iterator is created
        return !((Iterable) o).iterator().hasNext();
    }

    // reflection code

    final Number length = retrieveNumberFromMethod(o, "length");
    if (length != null) {
        return length.shortValue() <= 0;
    }

    final Number size = retrieveNumberFromMethod(o, "size");
    if (size != null) {
        return size.shortValue() <= 0;
    }

    final Boolean isEmpty = retrieveBooleanFromMethod(o, "isEmpty");
    if (isEmpty != null) {
        return isEmpty;
    }

    return false;
}

static Number retrieveNumberFromMethod(final Object o, final String methodName) {
    try {
        final Number number = (Number) o.getClass().getMethod(methodName).invoke(o);
        return number;
    }
    catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to retrieve number from " + methodName + " on " + o, e);
    }
    catch (final SecurityException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to retrieve number from " + methodName + " on " + o, e);
    }
    catch (final InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to retrieve number from " + methodName + " on " + o, e);
    }
    catch (final IllegalAccessException e) {
        return null;
    }
    catch (final NoSuchMethodException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

static Boolean retrieveBooleanFromMethod(final Object o, final String methodName) {
    try {
        final Boolean bool = (Boolean) o.getClass().getMethod(methodName).invoke(o);
        return bool;
    }
    catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to retrieve boolean from " + methodName + " on " + o, e);
    }
    catch (final SecurityException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to retrieve boolean from " + methodName + " on " + o, e);
    }
    catch (final InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to retrieve boolean from " + methodName + " on " + o, e);
    }
    catch (final IllegalAccessException e) {
        return null;
    }
    catch (final NoSuchMethodException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion this is very bad habit in java. This method will be "very heavy" because of many instanceof checks or try/catch recursions. Additionally some examples above leads to you loosing info if collection is NULL or it just empty.
In OBJ-C this is no problem because you can always call method on nil pointer, however this is very different for java. I believe this may lead to many problems with proper control of algorithms. For example you may do condition like

```
if (Helper.isEmpty(someList) == true) {
    someList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and if this is array which is passed down by several method calls as a buffer for arguments, this may lead to error which will be very hard to find.

Basically on enter to your method you know what type of object appears, so you can do check instantly, without going into long type checking method which after several if's discovers argument type which knowledge you have from very beginning.

Comment: Good answer. Although pgreen2's answer works, the real issue seems to be that Objective-C's weak typing makes it fundamentally different to Java, and some practices do not translate well from Objective-C to Java ("square peg, round hole").

Answer (score 1):

Check out class `Class` and class `Method` in Java, which led me to the following implementation for `isEmpty`:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(Object o) {
   try {
      return o == null ||
            (0 == (int)(((Class<? extends Object>) (o.getClass()))
              .getMethod("size", (Class[]) null).invoke(o, (Object[]) null)));
   } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
         | InvocationTargetException | SecurityException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return true;
   } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
      return true;
   }
}
```

For methods which take arguments, replace the `null`s in `getMethod()` and `invoke()` as per the documentation for `Method` and `Class`.

ADDENDUM

I knew that `size()` returns an int, so I was casting the result of `invoke()` with impunity.  This revised implementation of `isEmpty()` is cleaner and more explicit about what it's doing:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(Object o) {
   if (o != null) {
      Class<? extends Object> c = o.getClass();
      try {
         Method m = c.getMethod("size", (Class[]) null);
         Integer result = (Integer) m.invoke(o, (Object[]) null);
         if (result.intValue() > 0) {
            return false;
         }
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
         // o doesn't have a "size", so we'll quietly move on to return true
         // indicating this object is non-accessible
      } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
            | InvocationTargetException | SecurityException e) {
         // got something unexpected, let's show how we got here and then
         // return true, indicating this object is non-accessible
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but when I paste all of the above code into IntelliJ IDEA 12 with javac 1.6 and 1.7, the isEmpty method shows an `Inconvertible types; Cannot cast `java.lang.Object` to int'` error and red syntax highlighting. Does it compile for you? Which JDK and IDE?

Comment: @SteveHHH Compiles and runs fine for me in Java 1.7 on OS X Mountain Lion, I composed it in Eclipse.  You could break it up into stages, creating the intermediate Class and Method objects to see where specifically IntelliJ is choking.